# Can't install new pypi packages on Google Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-iam, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using *Google Cloud Composer* with version `composer-1.8.0-airflow-1.10.3` for scheduling our pipelines on GCP.

Lately, when we need to add some new Python packages to the environment (whether using Terraform or Cloud Console), we keep getting a strange error message but Cloud Composer is still up and new packages not installed.

The error message that appears on Cloud Composer UI :

> Resource not found (resource=europe-west1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-composer-backend-sub-3fb66162-3xxxd-4f43-ba47-xxxxxx)., Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional errors: {"originalResponse":"{\"paths\":[\"/apis\",\"/apis/\",\"/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io\",\"/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1\",\"/healthz\",\"/healthz/etcd\",\"/healthz/log\",\"/healthz/ping\",\"/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced\",\"/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers\",\"/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers\",\"/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers\",\"/metrics\",\"/openapi/v2\",\"/version\"]}","reason":"The descriptor url 'https://35.187.59.32/swaggerapi/apis/batch/v1' for type provider 'europe-west1-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-addons-job-typer' could not be fetched."} , Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional errors: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/storage-v1:storage.objects.list","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"xxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to composer-unlistable.","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"xxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to composer-unlistable.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/composer-unlistable/o","httpMethod":"GET","suggestion":"Consider granting permissions to xxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}

When looking to the *Stackdriver logging*, we can find this error message which is associated with that environment update:

> status: {
>      code: 9
>      message: "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
>     }

Any idea on what causes this behavior and how to resolve it?

**EDIT:**

Note that `xxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` is the service account used by Google for internal communication which is not manageable on IAM page (see [Service Account Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?&_ga=2.229816219.-62512895.1568807104#google-managed_service_accounts)).

Also, we noticed that sometimes adding a new package works correctly. But next time we try to add another package it fails with the same error message as above.

Comment: Did you upgrade your airflow version to 1.10.3 soon before you started getting this error? Also, have you manually upgraded the GKE cluster of the environment to version 1.14++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error by manually upgrading the GKE cluster of the Composer environment (composer-1.8.2-airflow-1.10.3) to 1.14.8-gke.12:

[image]

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/upgrading#limitations), *Composer environments not using private IP should not upgrade GKE to 1.14+. These versions have [deprecated Swagger in favor of OpenAPI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#openapi-and-swagger-definitions). A future Cloud Composer release will create clusters that use OpenAPI and will enable upgrading existing environments to GKE versions 1.14 and beyond.*

Currently, OpenAPI is used only for private IP environments and as a result, there is no issue there.

Unfortunately, there is no way to downgrade your GKE cluster, so the only solution would be to delete and recreate your environment.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. We recreated the environment with GKE version 1.13. Thank you!

Comment: This is so ridiculous. Would upgrading GKE to `1.15.x` break anything else? I'm now stuck on `1.14.10` with this same issue. I'm trying to scale up the cluster, but get the error above.

Comment: Worse yet: I just created a new Composer environment. There were no options for the GKE version. It defaulted to `1.14.10-gke.17` where I can't install `pandas`. What can one possibly do? On my previous environment (the one that I manually upgraded GKE from 1.13 to 1.14) I tried upgrading to 1.15, and same issue. Is Cloud Composer completely useless now?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like service `xxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` account does not have the correct permissions. In the IAM section add the 'Storage Object Viewer' role to this service account.

Comment: Actually, this is a google internal service account. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?&_ga=2.229816219.-62512895.1568807104#google-managed_service_accounts

Comment: Yes I am aware. You need to make sure those permissions are available to that service account.